# How do I convert tile pixels to longitude and latitude for web mercator?

Tags: web-mercator

I need a function to convert from tile pixels (x, y) from the Web Mercator projection (aka EPSG::3857 or SRID 900913), to longitude and latitude.

I'd like the function to be written in pseudo-code or a language like C.  I'm writing a C++ program.

I apologize if this is a duplicate question but I'm having trouble finding the algorithm.

I have found [an algorithm that converts longitude and latitude to tile pixels.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-maps-api/xjCy7LjNdhw)  But I'm not confident that I can rewrite it to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2):

you can find a lot of formulas with nice explanation in this wonderful page:

http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/

They are in python but code is quite simple. Have fun!